# How to get the url from a link field in preprocess function

Tags: 8

- I have a content type event.
- It has a link `field field_event_location_link`
- Both the link text and url are optional

By default Drupal uses the url as the title if there is no title typed in.

I want to show 'Location' if the title is not filled in.

How can I use a preprocess function to see if there is a title, and if not, use my string.

I tried ...

```
function my_module_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_event_location_link') {
    if ($variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'] == '') {
     $variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = 'Location';
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work and I think it's because by the time I get to that point, Drupal has already used the uri for the #title.

**Question:**
Can I catch it before that?
Or can I get a variable for the URL and use that variable in the `''` above? Should I be checking if something is empty...?

Comment: Have you also tried to check if it not isset? As in `if (!isset($variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'])) { ...`?

Comment: Sadly, this produced an error: `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`. The suggestion of `if (null !== ($variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'])) {` didn't work either, if statement didn't check out.

Comment: Try to dump the value of the field using print_r for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect with `$variables['items'][0]['content']` with [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) kint

```
kint($variables['items'][0]['content']);
```

[image]

> But it doesn't work and I think it's because by the time I get to that
>   point, Drupal has already used the uri for the #title.

Correct, so all you gotta do is check if the title is equal to the url utilizing [Url::toString](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AtoString/8.2.x).

```
  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_event_location_link') {
    $link_url = $variables['items'][0]['content']['#url']->toString();
    if ($variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'] == $link_url) {
      $variables['items'][0]['content']['#title'] = 'Location';
    }
  }
```